# Commas meaning change

Tags: meaning

> Ye shall not make any cutting in your flesh for the dead, nor print any marks upon you.

Does the comma make it two different subject or the same. Like Ye shall not make any cutting in your flesh nor print any marks upon you for the dead. As a lot of people say it's the same meaning.

I read the quote differently depending on whether the two parts have the same subject:

- **same subject**: don't do either of the actions on yourself *for the dead*.
- **different subjects**: the first action is prohibited (only) if done *for the dead*, while the prohibition of the second is absolute.

Comment: If they were different subjects, what would you say the sentence would/could mean?

Comment: That the cutting is the only one referring to the dead and the printing any marks on you has nothing to do with the dead, some say that the comma makes that they are referring to not doing to the dead?

Comment: Hmm ... fair enough; I should have asked it the other way. Since the second prohibition relates to "upon *you*", how would you interpret the sentence if you considered the two parts to have a common subject?

Comment: I read it as two different. Ye shall not make any cutting in you flesh for the dead,  Nor print any mark upon you. If they mean the same should it not read Ye shall not make any cutting I. Your flesh, nor print any mark upon you for the dead

Comment: Are you saying that because both are to do with our flesh cutting, printing that they both should not be done for the dead

Comment: The comma does tend to (further) separate the second part from the context "for the dead" of the first. But unless the broader context suggests that "for the dead" was implied for the second part, I think the 'different subjects' interpretation is stronger regardless of the presence of the comma.

Comment: The King James Bible (1611/1769) puts a comma in that place [Leviticus 19:28](http://textusreceptusbibles.com/Interlinear/3019028) and Young's Literal Bible (1862) makes the point even stronger by using a semi colon.

Comment: I think that belongs in a Bible commentary but since you asked, how could it reasonably mean different things? "Ye shall not make any cutting in your flesh for the dead, nor print any marks upon you" might be rather old-fashioned but still, how does it not have exactly the same meaning as "Ye shall not make any cutting in your flesh, nor print any marks upon you, for (anything. Please, don't get bogged down by the reason)"?